# PHP: how to echo string that contains both ' and "

Tags: php, html

Trying to echo the following

```
echo (
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": false,
     "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
     "dom": '<"top"lp>',
     "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0 ] }
       ],
     "aoColumns" : [
          { sWidth: '3%' },
          { sWidth: '45%' },
          { sWidth: '45%' },
          { sWidth: '7%' }
        ]  
  } );
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
$('#dataTables_filter').keyup(function(){
      oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() );
})
} );
</script>
);
```

As you can see it contains a lot of `'` and `"` way too often and it would be a pain to add a `\` to echo it properly. Is there any other way? I searched in stackoverflow and didn't find anything so far...

Comment: Why do you wrap it around an `echo` ?

Comment: You could either escape from PHP, or use a HereDoc

Comment: @Daan to show you what i am trying to echo

Comment: Yes but why do you need to echo it?

Comment: [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [NOWDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into php mode only when you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Use heredoc strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

All inside it'll be as a string without quotes:

```
echo <<<EOT
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": false,
     "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
     "dom": '<"top"lp>',
     "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0 ] }
       ],
     "aoColumns" : [
          { sWidth: '3%' },
          { sWidth: '45%' },
          { sWidth: '45%' },
          { sWidth: '7%' }
        ]  
  } );
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
$('#dataTables_filter').keyup(function(){
      oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() );
})
} );
</script>
EOT;
```

Be careful to write the end label 'EOT' without any indentation.

Comment: `echo '<<<EOT  sometext  EOT;'`  like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Leave PHP mode. Go back into it only when you need to do processing of data or access to variables.

```
function functionName() {
    ?>
        <script>
           // free text
           var foo = <?php echo json_encode($some_variable); ?>;
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I need to do this in a php function

Comment: @Shiro you can escape from PHP in a function, it will function the same as calling `echo` or `print`

Comment: @Shiro It will work inside a function to replace echo.

Comment: @Daan The answer is absolutely fine!

Comment: @Shiro — You can do that inside a function.

Comment: @worldofjr It's not what the OP is asking, you don't know why the OP wants to wrap an echo around his jQuery.

Comment: @Daan — That's if you take the question to mean "Must use the echo function" instead of "Has the same effect as using the echo function".

Comment: @Daan This method is functionally the same as using echo. You're not the OP, so kindly let them speak for themselves.

Comment: @worldofjr I'm not saying it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = <<<EOF
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": false,
    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "dom": '<"top"lp>',
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0 ] }
    ],
        "aoColumns" : [
        { sWidth: '3%' },
        { sWidth: '45%' },
        { sWidth: '45%' },
        { sWidth: '7%' }
    ]  
} );
oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
$('#dataTables_filter').keyup(function(){
    oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() );
})
} );
</script>
EOF;

echo $str;
```